# Terminology to indicate functions convex in certain arguments

Tags: convex-analysis, terminology

What's the appropriate terminology to indicate functions convex only in certain arguments?
For example, consider the following function.

$f: X \times Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f(x, \cdot)$ is convex.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convex function wrt. an argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2372316/convex-function-wrt-an-argument)

Comment: @MarkS. I saw it and understood the notion but the answer does not tell us the terminology for such functions.

Comment: The question author used "convex [wrt.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/WRT#English) its second argument" and [the accepted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2372343/26369) used "convex w.r.t. $w$". So "$f$ is convex with respect to its second argument (for all $x\in X$)" or "$f$ is convex with respect to $y$" would be appropriate for your example.

Comment: Actually, I googled papers with keyword "convex w.r.t. certain argument" but I can find only few papers. Anyway, thanks for answering :) @MarkS.